# Sync SQL Server with IOS Sqlite

Tags: ios, sql-server, zumero

I have the following components

1. SQL Database Server
2. Web Server with web services
3. IOS Device with app written in Xamarin

The IOS app talks to the webservices to update SQL Server database.

What is the best way (tool) to sync the database? Its a small configuration database only. I have only looked into Zumero